# How to display Image when button1 is pressed

Tags: java

How can i display and image when button1 is pressed, this is the code im using to check for a button press:

```
public class clientFrameButtons {
   public void frameClient(){........

....

button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ //ActionListener checks for button press
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        // if button is pressed the following will happen
```

I've tried implementing an if statement and looked at several sources online but cannot find a answer to fit my needs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActionEvent` is a *logical* event those intention is to signal the fact that a button was actioned. So it doesn't provide any information about the user inputs that have lead to the action (it may be a shortcut, a mouse press, your mouse could have been set to left-handed, etc). If you want to care about mouse, then you must catch mouse events, with an appropriate `MouseListener`.

So your problem can be expressed in two ways:

1. you want to display an image when a GUI button is actioned then use `ActionListener`.
2. you want to make different things depending on the mouse button pressed while over a GUI button, then use `MouseListener`.

Comment: Okay, i see what you mean. Thank you for your reply!